# Ubuntu 18.04 can't boot

Tags: boot, 18.04

after upgrading Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04

it doesn't boot at first the screen freezes then it goes black !!

although I can boot in ( nomodeset ) it disable Intel integrated graphics and LLVM is shown as graphics instead in my system settings and the system is unable to detect the res of my display after that the system becomes very laggy

does anyone knows how to deal with this situation

this is my system information and specs you might want to take a look at it

[System information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKlrd.jpg)

in nomodeset the system shows LLVM instead my integrated graphics

[LLVM instead of my Intel graphics !!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG48Y.png)

Comment: This seems rather similar to [the question you asked yesterday](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051617/).

Comment: yes nomodeset caused this issue but now Ubuntu doesn't boot i'm trying to install bionic beaver on my old PC and get it to work and I want a solution